# How can I implement this string generation behavior starting from a given number?

Tags: c#, string

I have to implement the following behavior using C#

I give a number, something like: 1 or 2 or 35 or 958 and starting from this number I have to build a string that is the concatenation of n 0 values followed by the given number.

The string lenght is fixed and is 7 character.

I will do some example to better explain my use case:

- If the given number is **1** the build string will be: **0000001**
- If the given number is **37** the build string will be: **0000037**
- If the given number is **252** the build string will be: **0000252**

and so on.

What could be a smart way to implement this behavior in C#?

Comment: Whats about `.ToString("0000000`")`?

Comment: the first possible value is 0000001